# How can I make a jsonp request in php?

Tags: php, laravel

I used laravel in my project. I need to seed user login request to another API site from my laravel site. It's also a CORS request so the auth API requires a jsonp request.

Comment: "It's also a CORS request so the auth API requires a jsonp request" — That is… nonsense. The Same Origin Policy doesn't apply to PHP in the first place. Even if it did, CORS is a **replacement** for JSONP, so you would never need JSONP if CORS was supported.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try [cURL](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php)

```
        $ch = curl_init(); 
        $url ='http://www.example.com/api?valueName='.$value.'&callback=?';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // remove body 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
        $head = curl_exec($ch); 
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
        curl_close($ch);
```

Or [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/api?valueName='.$value.'&callback=?');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the setCallback method with the json method in laravel like this -

```
return response()->json(['status' => 'success', 'code' => '201'])
                 ->setCallback($request->input('callback'));
```